# button1.setButton(false) will not link up with my other code

Tags: java, swing

Explanation:
Hi, I am creating my clicker game and I can't find out why my button1.setEnabled(false); code wont link to my JButton button1 = new JButton("Hacker Level: "); . I am using two buttons. The first button starts a timer and counts the number of clicks/space bar presses. Once 10 seconds run out, the button disables itself. The second button resets the number of clicks and enables the first button.

Problem:
Because of me using two different buttons, I have to use JButton and it won't make it link up to the button1.setEnabled(false); code. How can I link it up?

[when the timer runs out, set button1 to disable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO9Rj.png)
.
[button1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTdSl.png)
This is the part of the code that is the problem:

```
        public TestPane() {

        new GridLayout(0, 1); // 0 rows, 1 column

        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (startTime < 0) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long clockTime = now - startTime;
                if (clockTime >= duration) {
                    clockTime = duration;
                    timer.stop();

                    **button1.setEnabled(false);**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

                }
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");
                label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);

        // \/ label wrapper \/ TITLE
        label = new JLabel("Hacker GUI v1", JLabel.CENTER); // label text
        label.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 20)); // font size

        add(label); // add the label
        // /\ label wrapper /\

        // \/ label wrapper \/ DESCRIPTION
        label = new JLabel("To hack, click on the button or press space while on the window.", JLabel.CENTER); // text label
        label.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 15)); // font size
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

        add(label); // add the label
        // /\ label wrapper /\

        // \/ button wrapper \/ BUTTON PLAY
        Dimension d = new Dimension(215, 30); // first number is length (left to right), second number is heigh (top to bottom).

        **JButton button1 = new JButton("Hacker Level: "); // button text**<<<<<<<<<<<<
        button1.setPreferredSize(d); // size of button relitive to dimension d
        button1.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 15)); //font size of button
        button1.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++; //count in positive integers
                button1.setText("Hacker Level: " + count); //text change when action preformed

                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    startTime = -1;
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
            
        });

        add(button); //add the button
        //     /\ button wrapper /\


        // \/ button wrapper \/ BUTTON RESET
        Dimension a = new Dimension(215, 30); // first number is length (left to right), second number is heigh (top to bottom).

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Reset Score"); // button text
        button2.setPreferredSize(a); // size of button relitive to dimension d
        button2.setFont(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 15)); //font size of button
        button2.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++; //count in positive integers
                button1.setText("Hacker Level: " + count); //text change when action preformed

                button1.setEnabled(true);

            }
            
        });

        add(button); //add the button
        //     /\ button wrapper /\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("Hacker Level: ");
```

You are defining a local variable. A local variable can't be used in other methods.

You need to define "button1" as an instance variable (the same way you define your labels):

```
button1 = new JButton("Hacker Level: ");
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have also added these two lines of code: private JButton button1; private JButton button2;

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare and set up button1 before using it. So try moving those few lines to somewhere before the timer line.